# Função onClick sendo chamada quando os componentes são renderizados

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Tenho essa função chamada `Logout`

```
function Logout() {
        authService.logout();
        localStorage.removeItem("connectado");
    }
```

e chamei ela desta forma no `onClick={Logout()}` e mesmo alterando para uma arrow function ainda assim o mesmo efeito acontecia:

```
const Logout = () => {
        authService.logout();
        localStorage.removeItem("connectado");
    }
```

Consegui resolver apenas retirando o **()** do **onClick**, mas o que me intriga é que esta sendo executado como se fosse um hook useEffect, já refiz da mesma forma varias vezes e mesmo assim o efeito continua, será que foi proposital isso no React ou é só um bug?
Caso alguém possa explicar mais sobre porque não tenho muito conhecimento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você estava fazendo, ao renderizar o componente por inteiro, ele logo estava disparando uma a função do botão.
Para que isto não ocorra, o certo pode passar uma referência da função para o `onClick` e há três modos de fazer uma seria usando o `bind`, outra usando uma arrow function dentro do onClick, que é mais comum hoje em dia.
E quando você passa um `onClick={function()}` logo ao renderizar, esta função será disparada, algo que também pode ser trocado por `onClick={function}`.

`onClick={() => logout()}`. Ou até mesmo a forma que você fez, transformar a sua função em uma arrow function e apenas usar `onClick={logout}`.

[Documentação React.JS](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)